# Floating item in listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

i need to float the items in a listbox to make they appear like two for lines... how can i? i've tried but they continue to appear one after another... my xml:

```
    <ListBox Name="listacomico" Width="480" Margin="0,112,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Background="White" BorderBrush="#346699" Click="apri_comico" Name="{Binding Myordine}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="125">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Myimmagine}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: You don't make any sense at all.

Comment: someone can help me? is possible to make two item per rows?

Comment: Can you edit this question for clarity? I tried reading it several times and still can't quite figure out what you're asking.

Comment: In the listbox, one item is under another... ok?
I need two items per rows... the size of my items is right but i can't:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/listbox.jpg/

Comment: I'm thinking a WrapPanel here. But a example would probably be a waste of effort on this guy.

Comment: can you help me or just write inutil things?
i'm new to widows phone, ok, but i'm ready to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display items next to each other you'll have to use a WrapPanel as it has been suggested in the comments above.

It's not a behavior related to the ItemTemplate. ItemTemplate will define how items look like.

To achieve what you want to do, you have to define the **ItemsPanel** like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

**toolkit:** means that I have a namespace called toolkit on the top of my xaml:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

You'll have to add a reference to the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) to your project if it's not already done!

Comment: thanks a lot! it works!
i've already the toolkit because i use the transition effect.

now that i'm here... can i ask you something? i need to replace the source of an image via xaml.cs, i have this in the xaml: <Image Source="/" Name="faccia" Width="125" Height="95" Margin="0,112,0,0" /> and this in the .cs: faccia.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Myapp;component/comici/" + url_img.Value)); but it doesn't display anything!

Comment: Are you sure the Uri is correct? You can add an eventhandler on the ImageFailed event to make sure: <Image ImageFailed="eventhandler"/>
But is there a good reason to load the image from code-behind? Couldn't you use Binding?